# add reference line in ecdf ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ecdf

I am trying to add a reference line to my ecdf graph in R.
Here is what my data looks like.

```
dput(head(pppp))
structure(list(B_code= c(1121058L, 1121058L, 1121058L, 1121058L, 
1121058L, 1121058L), Distance = c(0.9, 1.3, 1.6, 1.9, 2.1, 2.2
), AI_i = c(422.717247745409, 51.1207837179096, 70.5839979587593, 
13.5040949782694, 371.762616959738, 21.395033572169)), row.names = c("107924", 
"107922", "107925", "107910", "107933", "107923"), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

The code I implied is

```
   
  pppp<-pppp[c(order(pppp$Distance)),]
  AI = pppp$AI_i                      
  val<-ecdf(AI)
  par(new=T)
  ggplot(test2, aes(AI)) + 
    stat_ecdf(geom = "line") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +     
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
    xlab("Calculated Accessibility Value") +
    ylab("Percent")
```

What code should I use to add a horizontal and vertical reference line to the x and y value with 0.7% of ecdf?
I would like the first x value to be represented with y value 0.7.

I would appreciate some suggestions or help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `geom_hline()` and `geom_vline()`.

Comment: I was thinking about this solution as well. Is there a way I can get the first 70% x value in my data set without setting the values of x myself? I am quite weak at computing and coding. I apologize if I am asking something obvious

Comment: You could try `geom_vline(xintercept = 0.7 * sum(AI))`